# Show information about picked points of matplotlib pick_event in a HTML div

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make an interactive scatter plot with matplotlib, in a jupyter notebook. Now for each picked point, I would like to show some additional information (not in text, but actually some 3D plots that could only be done by HTML+javascript).

Since I am new to mpl, I start with a very simple example (as shown below). In my imagination, I could either display(HTML(".....")), or call some function to run another cell (by calling run_cell_by_tag(tag)) in the jupyter notebook that do the 3D plot stuffs. However, in my attempts neither could work...

Any suggestion would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
%%javascript
window.findCellIndicesByTag = function findCellIndicesByTag(tagName) {
  return (Jupyter.notebook.get_cells()
    .filter(
      ({metadata: {tags}}) => tags && tags.includes(tagName)
    )
    .map((cell) => Jupyter.notebook.find_cell_index(cell))
  );
};
window.runCells = function runCellsByTag(tags) {
    var c = window.findCellIndicesByTag(tags);
    Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells(c);
};



from IPython.core.display import Javascript
from IPython.display import display
def run_cell_by_tag(tags):
    display(Javascript("window.runCells('"+tags+"')"))


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure('Test')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
true = [1,2,3,4]
pred = [1.1, 2.5, 3.1, 3.9]
line, = ax.plot(true, pred, 'o', picker=5, color='red') 
picked, = ax.plot([],[], 'o', color='yellow')
text = ax.text(0,0,"")
selected_ind = []
def onpick(event):
    thispoint = event.artist
    xdata = thispoint.get_xdata()
    ydata = thispoint.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    selected_ind.append(ind[0])
    text.set_position((xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    text.set_text(str(ind[0]) +":true="+ str(xdata[ind[0]])+",pred=" + str(ydata[ind[0]])[:3])
    picked.set_data(xdata[ind[0]], ydata[ind[0]])

    ##Is it possible to call "run_cell_by_tag", or display(HTML("")) here?? 
    ##I need to pass over "ind" to make the 3D plot<---------------


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

[This is what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWx6e.png)